# Forbidden from empty user "" kuberntes

Tags: kubernetes

This is command

```
kubectl --namespace=somenamespace   exec -it test sh
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "test" is forbidden: User "" cannot create resource
```

There is my kube config

```
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: "test" # refers to aws profile test located in ~/.aws/config,
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
      - "token"
      - "-i"
      - "qa"
```

aws config is

```
[profile test]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::66776776:role/AssumeRoleReadOnly
source_profile = sso
region = us-east-1
```

I dont understand why user is empty "" and I got forbidden error

Comment: I use wrong  aws role so close this question